# Spring boot metrics http.server.requests showing root

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

So i set up a spring hello world service with spring security configured.

my hello world endpoint doesnt seem to appear in the http server requests metrics. Why am i unable to get the /helloworld endpoint to be collected

{
"tag": "uri",
"values": [
"/actuator/health/**",
"/actuator",
"/actuator/metrics",
"root"
]
}

Other projects without security i noticed no root, but had the relevant endpoints in the values array.